# Google Signin button in Google-Site give blank screen popup

Tags: html, google-signin

I have a Google domain and a new Google Site. I want to add a Google Signin button.
But whatever I try, I only get a blank screen that pops up when clicking the signin button.
I have created an OAuth consent screen. I have created a client-ID. I generated the integration code as described in https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator.
The code was embedded in the site.
But the button did not appear.
When I explictely loaded the client library with
`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`
the button appears, but now I get an error when I inspect the page:
`[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.`
Clicking on the button gives a blank screen.
**Question**: what am I doing wrong?
The HTML code:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="147904889152-dpkd99nltl33r9f2rprctsfu9u04m6qa.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-context="signup"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="thembaheino.nl/test"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you follow steps from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id)? When generating the Web application-type client ID, what exactly did you specified in the `Authorized JavaScript origins` section?

Comment: With OAuth consent screen in 'Test' I specified the domain https://thembaheino.nl (you are free to use, only for testing) and http://localhost. In the documentation it is advised to add an origin with localhost with portnumber. But I don't know which portnumber to use. However, with published consent screen it doesn't work either

Comment: Try `https://thembaheino.nl` and `https://www.thembaheino.nl` to be set as origins, also based on the HTML code above, `data-login_uri="thembaheino.nl/test"` is this the correct login endpoint?

Comment: Lorena, thanks for your reply. 1) I did add these urls to be set as origins. 2) What needs to be set in the login endpoint? I would like users to go to this page after login. But apart from the library ```c<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>``` the page is empty. Please check the site ```thembaheino.nl``` The button Google Signin will result in blank window.